# Ensure div parent wraps img child

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I'm building a "resize image" feature for my app. However in setting it up, I am running into difficulties getting the draggable handles of the element to cleanly wrap around the image, like this:

[image]

With my code, it seems like the size of the div is based on thewindow and not the image.

This is my code so far, you can see it in action on Stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uolcai):

**index.html**

```
<figure class="figure mb-4 mt-2 text-center">
  <app-resize-container>
    <img
      class="figure-img rounded"
      src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/600/600"
      style="margin: 0px;"
    />
  </app-resize-container>
  <figcaption [style.marginTop.em]="1" class="figure-caption text-center">
    Test
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

**resize-container.component.html**

```
<div class="resize-container">
  <div class="resize-container-handler">
    <div
      *ngFor="let resizeCornerSetting of resizeCornerSettings; let i = index"
      [ngClass]="resizeCornerSetting.class"
    >
      <div class="resize-corner-handle">
        <div class="resize-element-size-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

***resize-container.component.ts***

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { IResizeCornerSettings } from './course-content-element-item-resize-container';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-course-content-element-item-resize-container',
  templateUrl: './course-content-element-item-resize-container.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-content-element-item-resize-container.component.css'],
})
export class CourseContentElementItemResizeContainerComponent {
  @Input() width: number | undefined | null;
  resizeCornerSettings: IResizeCornerSettings[] = [
    {
      position: ['top', 'left'],
      class: 'resize-corner-container resize-corner-top-left',
    },
    {
      position: ['top', 'right'],
      class: 'resize-corner-container resize-corner-top-right',
    },
    {
      position: ['bottom', 'left'],
      class: 'resize-corner-container resize-corner-bottom-left',
    },
    {
      position: ['bottom', 'right'],
      class: 'resize-corner-container resize-corner-bottom-right',
    },
  ];
}
```

***resize-container.component.css***

```
.resize-container {
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #335eea !important;
}

.resize-container-handler {
  z-index: 3;
  overflow: visible;
  min-inline-size: max-content;
  min-width: 30px;
  min-height: 30px;
  will-change: width, height, transform;
}

.resize-corner-container {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: auto;
  display: flex;
}

.resize-corner-handle {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 1px rgba(14, 19, 24, 0.15),
    0 0 0 1px rgba(14, 19, 24, 0.2);
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.resize-corner-top-right {
  z-index: 1;
  top: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  cursor: nesw-resize;
}

.resize-corner-top-left {
  z-index: 1;
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  cursor: nwse-resize;
}

.resize-corner-bottom-right {
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: -15px;
  right: -15px;
  cursor: nwse-resize;
}

.resize-corner-bottom-left {
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  cursor: nesw-resize;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing `display: inline-block;` on parent divs `.resize-container` and `.resize-container-handler`. Just add `display: inline-block` and it will start working.

```
.resize-container {
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid #335eea !important;
  display: inline-block; /*Added this */
}

.resize-container-handler {
  z-index: 3;
  overflow: visible;
  min-inline-size: max-content;
  min-width: 30px;
  min-height: 30px;
  will-change: width, height, transform;
  display: inline-block; /*Added this */
}
```

See [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4tqbs4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fresize-container%2Fresize-container.component.css)

Comment: Thanks for this, how would it work in a scenario where the image has a width of 75%? See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lujpgj

Comment: I am not sure but you should not give width to image instead you should restrict the parent div `.resize-container`'size. You are going to scale parent up or down not image unless you have requirement to scale image on resize.

Comment: You can also set image as background image of `resize-container`.